# Django - can you make a subclass of a model just to alter behavior?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking to do the opposite of what Django's proxy model does. I want to subclass Model, add some extra methods to it, add behavior to `save()`, set a default manager that adds some my-application-specific methods, and then subclass that to create most of the models in my application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just sounds like a simple case of model inheritance with an [abstract base class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

Comment: oh excellent. Thanks. For some reason I read that as having it's own table because I saw the attributes. That's even better than because I can have custom behavior and define attributes that will reside in child models.